# Characters not getting converted to lower case , eventhough the string has all lower case letters

Tags: java, string, character, primitive-types, stringbuffer

Trying to solve a leetcode problem of "valid palindrome" below is the code . when I convert the stringbuffer to string and to lower case the string is getting printed as all lower case letters, but when I access it for comparisons using s.charAt(i), I am getting the uppercase letters as well.

```
 public static void main(String []args){

     String s = "aA";

    String[] strings = s.split("[^A-Za-z0-9]");
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(); 

    for(int i =0; i<strings.length;i++){
        sb.append(strings[i]);
    }
    String newString = sb.toString().toLowerCase();
    System.out.println("New String "+newString);***// output : aa(lower case)***

    for(int i =0; i<newString.length()/2;i++){
        if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(newString.length()-i-1)){
             System.out.println(s.charAt(i));//**output 'a**
             System.out.println(s.charAt(newString.length()-i-1));//***output 'A'***
        }

    }
```

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  `s` is always `"aA"` in this code.

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying `s`, the lower case string is in `newString`. You need to replace the variable inside the second for:

```
for(int i =0; i<newString.length()/2;i++){
        if(newString.charAt(i) != newString.charAt(newString.length()-i-1)){
             System.out.println(s.charAt(i));//**output 'a**
             System.out.println(s.charAt(newString.length()-i-1));//***output 'A'***
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to get lowercase then use `newString` variable instead of String `s`;

```
for(int i =0; i<newString.length()/2;i++){
    if(newString.charAt(i) != newString.charAt(newString.length()-i-1)){
         System.out.println(newString.charAt(i));
         System.out.println(newString.charAt(newString.length()-i-1));
    }
```

}

If you are planning to check the palindrome or not then the following can be one solution.

```
    String s = "aA";

    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(s);
    String reverse = stringBuffer.reverse().toString().toLowerCase();

    if (reverse.equals(s.toLowerCase())) {
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not palindrome");
    }
```